# NSFetchedResultsController / Parent-Child

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I'm working on my first Core Data-backed app and am having trouble figuring out how to set up an NSFetchedResultsController properly.  I have two entities:

```
/-----------\        /-----------\
| List      |        | ListItem  |
| --------- |        | --------- |
| listName  |        | itemName  |
| --------- |        | --------- |
| listItems |<---->> | list      |
\ --------- /        \ --------- /
```

I have two views (each inherit from `UITableViewController` and each are backed by a `NSFetchedResultsController`).  The first view is a `UITableView` that displays all of the `List` items.  When a row is selected, it pushes the second view.

I have a property in the view controller called `@property (strong, nonatomic) List *selectedList` which I assign with the selected `List` before I push the view.

What I'm having trouble setting up is having the second view only display the `ListItem` objects whose parent is the selected `List`.  I know that this belongs somewhere in the `NSFetchedResultsController`, but I don't know quite where.

Here's my code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Set up the fetched results controller.
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ListItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Detail"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Do I need to add some sort of a sort descriptor, or does the answer lie with something else?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `NSPredicate` to select the `ListItem`s where `selectedList` matches their `list` property.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"list == %@", self.selectedList];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

There's one thing to be aware of here and that is that the predicate will change depending on `selectedList` meaning that the fetch request will change. If you will be changing the fetch request, Apple has this warning in the [`NSFetchedResultsController` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW34).

> You cannot simply change the fetch request to modify the results. If
>   you want to change the fetch request, you must:
>
> 1. If you are using a cache, delete it (using **`+deleteCacheWithName:`**).
> 2. Typically you should not use a cache if you are changing the fetch request.
> 3. Change the fetch request. Invoke **`-performFetch:`**.